# How do I totally remove SQL Server 2017 on Ubuntu?

Tags: sql-server, linux, installation, ubuntu, sql-server-2017

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup#uninstall) has instructions about how to remove SQL Server.  However, this leaves certain packages behind.  How can I remove all traces and uninstall SQL Server 2017?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

These are actually *very* poor instructions on how to remove the Microsoft SQL Server.

SQL Server installs these associated packages.

```
mssql-server
mssql-server-fts
mssql-tools
msodbcsql
unixodbc-dev
```

Assuming you wish to totally remove SQL Server, you should

```
# Stop the service
systemctl stop mssql-server.service

sudo add-apt-repository --remove "$(curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/prod.list)"

# Remove those packages from the system.
sudo apt-get --purge remove mssql-server mssql-server-fts mssql-tools msodbcsql unixodbc-dev

# Delete the SQL Server repositories
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-* /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod*

# Remove the Microsoft keys.
apt-key del "BC52 8686 B50D 79E3 39D3  721C EB3E 94AD BE12 29CF"

# Delete the Microsoft created directories
sudo rm -rf /var/opt/mssql/ /opt/{microsoft,mssql-tools,mssql}/ /usr/share/doc/{msodbcsql,mssql-server,mssql-tools}
```