# Installing SQL Server 2017, I get E: Unable to locate package mssql-server

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu, sql-server-2017

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10, but after adding the Microsoft repo for 17.10

```
sudo add-apt-repository "$(curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -sr)/prod.list)"
```

and trying to install SQL Server, I get

```
# apt-get install mssql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mssql-server
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, a distro packages things in a specific format, so for instance adding a repository like

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/17.10/prod zesty main
```

Will tell `apt` to download a package list and look for the packages here,

```
https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/17.10/prod/pool/
```

However, with Microsoft that's not the case. They have a repository for 17.10 (as they should) which has all their packages for Ubuntu, but they have *another repository* specifically for SQL Server. To make matters more confusing, that SQL Server repository is in the tree of 16.04.

So they have both (pay attention to the `/pool/`s)

- https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server/pool/main/m/
- https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod/pool/main/m/

**You need** the `16.04/mssql-server` repository. You can add that with

```
sudo add-apt-repository "$(curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017.list)"
```

You may think because you have the `17.10/prod` and you have SQL Server installed that you don't need the `16.04/prod` repository. That's incorrect, **you'll need that too if you want the SQL Client `sqlcmd` [provided by mssql-tools](https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod/pool/main/m/)**

```
sudo add-apt-repository "$(curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list)"
```

I did file a [doc bug upstream with a description of the confusion so maybe they'll fix it someday](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/pull/299/commits/eabfcd0f1ad5ac864f798ae84fa252d2b7222b39)

If you find your system in an inconsistent state for any reason, you can [always remove SQL Server and start over](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/174175/2639).